# Mongodb - how can I query by date range?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I am new to Mongo.

I am trying to query for a date range. The user model has this field:

```
  field     :confirmed_at,          :type => Time
```

could someone help me write a query to get users who confirmed their account for some time range?

Here is the error and the query I am trying:

```
> db.users.where(:confirmed_at.gte => Time.now, :confirmed_at.lte => 10.minutes.ago)
Tue May 29 17:45:37 SyntaxError: syntax error (shell):1
Model.where(:confirmed_at.gte => Time.now, :confirmed_at.lte => 10.minutes.ago)
Tue May 29 17:56:15 SyntaxError: syntax error (shell):1
```

Thanks!

Comment: And why do you ask the same question twice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using mongoid by the way the field was declared.

You would want to use something like this:

```
Model.where(
  :confirmed_at.gte => Time.now,
  :confirmed_at.lte => 10.minutes.ago
)
```

Comment: thanks! yes I am using mongoid, but I am confused about how type is time and not date. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I tried something like this db.users.where((:confirmed_at.gte => "1980-1-1", :confirmed_at.lte => "2000-1-1") ) but that gave a syntax error

Comment: You have to parenthesis on the left side (near where).

Comment: this one also gives a syntax error :) db.users.where(:confirmed_at.gte => "1980-1-1", :confirmed_at.lte => "2000-1-1")

Comment: Updated my example, try that instead.

Comment: same thing..syntax error :) I am switching Model. to db.users.where

Comment: In the original question, please post the full model, the query, and the error.

Comment: You can't use db.collection in rails, that is shell syntax. Do it as I posted with the Model as the model name. In your case "Users". If you are trying to do this in the shell you will need to write the query a different way entirely. It would look like `db.users.find({created_at: {$gt: time1, $lt: time2}})`

Comment: I added what happenes after your suggestion..same thing :) Also added the model....thanks for your help!!